# Not working template filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a problem with time template filter.
I have a function in `models.py`, where I want to calculate time to next classes:

```
time_to = models.TimeField()

def get_time_to_next(self):
    return datetime.combine(datetime.today(), self.time_to) - \
        datetime.combine(datetime.today(), datetime.time(datetime.now()))
```

And I want to display this in a template as:

```
{{ next_classes.get_time_to_next|time:"H:i" }}
```

But template doesn't show anything. Time from function is max in hours, not in days or weeks or years....

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You are receiving no arguments for your function? is this all your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting two `datetime`s, which will result in a `timedelta`, and these are not supported by the `time` filter.  And actually, I think you are just getting an exception as `datetime.today()` returns a `datetime` and not just a day (use `date.today()` instead).  To make sure that your method does not raise an exception try it from the console `manage.py shell`.

This question [Displaying a timedelta object in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348003/displaying-a-timedelta-object-in-a-django-template) seem to provide a solution for displaying the `timedelta`.  However, you are probably better off returning a `datetime` object from `get_time_to_next()`.