# DurationField format

Tags: django, django-views

I have a `DurationField` defined in my model as

```
day0 = models.DurationField('Duration for Monday', default=datetime.timedelta)
```

When I try to view this, I want it formatted as "HH:MM" -- It is always less than 24.  So, I tried these in the HTML template file:

```
{{ slice.day0|time:'H:M' }}
{{ slice.day0|date:'H:M' }}
```

However, all I get is an empty space.

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display and format Django DurationField in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105457/display-and-format-django-durationfield-in-template)

Comment: Although it asks for a different output format, this question is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105457/display-and-format-django-durationfield-in-template/65293775.  I know this post is old and already has an answer, but I have answered it there in a more robust format, mostly for others and so that when I inevitably google this again and get this page as a result, I can see the answer that I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `timedelta` instance is not a `time` or a `datetime`. Therefore it does not make sense to use the `time` or `date` filters.

Django does not come with any template filters to display timedeltas, so you can either write your own, or look for an external app that provides them. You might find the template filters in [django-timedelta-field](https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-timedelta-field) useful.

Answer (score 5):

For posterity: here is what I used in the end. This is the content of `<app>/templatetags/datetime_filter.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Application filter for `datetime`_ 24 hours.

.. _datetime: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html
"""

from django import template
from datetime import date, timedelta

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='format_datetime')
def format_datetime(value):
    hours, rem = divmod(value.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
    return '{}h {}m'.format(hours, minutes)
```

Then in the view, add this:

```
{% load datetime_filter %}
[...]
{{ slice.day0|format_datetime }}
```