# How to format DurationField input as min:sec:millisec Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to force users to input lap times into a `Form` using the format min:sec:millisec (e.g. 00:00:000). I also want to display these times in this format in a `DetailView` but I want to store them as milliseconds to calculate personal bests and lap differences.

I have tried to set the default `DurationField` value as 01:01:001 but it displays in the format HH:MM:SS.MS
Here is my `model`:

```py
class SwimTime(models.Model):
    swimmer =models.ForeignKey(Swimmer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DurationField(_('Time'), default= timedelta(minutes=1, seconds=1, milliseconds=1))
    distance = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Distance'),null = False, default=50)
    strokeType = models.CharField(_('Stroke Type'),max_length=20, choices=strokeTypes, default='FC')
    date = models.DateField(_('Date Recorded'),default = timezone.now)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an "example" you can use [`help_text` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#help-text) for the field showing the expected input format. You can use it as any other option: default, null...

> help_text="Please use the following format: *YYYY-MM-DD*."

Anyway, this has nothing to do with how it will be rendered in any template or even in database or browser validation.

For templates you can use the Datetime formatting. Django has not built-in formatting as [it has for date and time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date), but there are some projects that solve that. Also, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105457/display-and-format-django-durationfield-in-template) there are some good examples for writing your own filters and load them in the template.

*Also, reading your data I guess that `null=False` is not necessary in 'distance' field: by default it will be set to False. And keep in mind that null=True and blank=True have different uses.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).